# Applying custom functions over lists of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I'm trying to optimize some working code by applying custom functions, but I'm not sure how to do it over specific columns in a large dataframe. In the example below, I'm selecting open-ended questions in my dataframe which is a survey. You'll see that I'm manually inputting each open-ended column manually, but I would like to just have a custom function that iterates through the openend list.

```
openend = ['Q28','Q56','Q63']
```

```
### Change ranges to match the above
open1 = df.iloc[:, 28:29] # isolates 'range'
open1 = open1.iloc[1:] # removes first row
open1 = pd.concat([ids, open1], axis=1) # adds ids

open2 = df.iloc[:, 56:57]
open2 = open2.iloc[1:]
open2 = pd.concat([ids, open2], axis=1)

open3 = df.iloc[:, 63:64]
open3 = open3.iloc[1:]
open3 = pd.concat([ids, open3], axis=1)
```

```
open1['question'] = df1['Q28'][0]
open1['answer'] = open1.iloc[:,1:2]
open1 = open1.drop(open1.iloc[:,1:2], axis=1)

open2['question'] = df1['Q56'][0]
open2['answer'] = open2.iloc[:,1:2]
open2 = open2.drop(open2.iloc[:,1:2], axis=1)

open3['question'] = df1['Q63'][0]
open3['answer'] = open3.iloc[:,1:2]
open3 = open3.drop(open3.iloc[:,1:2], axis=1)
```

```
open1_stack = open1
open2_stack = open2
open3_stack = open3
```

```
open1_stack["answer"] = open1_stack["answer"].str.upper().str.title()
open1_count = open1_stack.answer.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()
open1_count = open1_count.to_frame().reset_index()
open1_count.columns = ['Word', 'Count']
open1_count['question'] = df1['Q28'][0]

open2_stack["answer"] = open2_stack["answer"].str.upper().str.title()
open2_count = open2_stack.answer.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()
open2_count = open2_count.to_frame().reset_index()
open2_count.columns = ['Word', 'Count']
open2_count['question'] = df1['Q56'][0]

open3_stack["answer"] = open3_stack["answer"].str.upper().str.title()
open3_count = open3_stack.answer.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()
open3_count = open3_count.to_frame().reset_index()
open3_count.columns = ['Word', 'Count']
open3_count['question'] = df1['Q63'][0]
```

Can someone show me with this example how you would iterate through the openended list and apply these functions in an optimal way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap all of your code with a function that accepts the `openend` as a parameter and has a signature like:

```
def prepare_survey(openend:list):
```

Then loop through that list to extract `'QXX'`:

```
for q in openend:
    # process
```

I see that you are using the same content of `openend` with no changes, except for the first few steps where you extract the index. So, keep it as it is, but extract the question number, something like this:

```
import re

def prepare_survey(openend:list):
    for q in openend:
        # process
        idx = int(re.sub("[^0-9]", "", q))  # extract question number
        # continue with the steps you have
        open1 = df.iloc[:, idx:idx+1]
```